# commit to single table and roll back to others

Tags: db2

I have to create records in multiple tables one after another serially and if there is some exception in data I need to log it into some exception table.

The problem is in case of exception (which is a data related issue, nothing to do with DB) I need to rollback all the `Insert`s but the entry into the exception table shouldn't be rolled back.

What should I do as as per my understanding a `COMMIT` statement will commit all the `Insert`s along with the exception table `Insert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an `AUTONOMOUS` routine for logging.
Check the [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html) statement description.

> **AUTONOMOUS**
>   Indicates the procedure should execute in its own autonomous transaction scope.